# Formula in Excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am creating a line graph in Excel 2007. What I would like to achieve is to specify a formula in the chart data range.

What I have now in the chart data range is:

```
=SHEET1!$B$1:$W$1;SHEET1!$B$7:$W$7
```

This simply creates a line graph using the `B1,C1,D1,...` and `B7,C7,D7...` values.

However, I would like to manipulate the second data `($B$7:$W$7)` by dividing it another row and then use the result in the graph. So the result should be something like:

```
=SHEET1!$B$1:$W$1;SHEET1!($B$7:$W$7/$B$8:$W$8)
```

This formula returns error. I need B7 divided by B8, then C7 divided by C8 and so on. And the calculated result should be used in the graph.

PS: I know that I can easily create a new row for my calculation and create a graph with it. But I was wondering if that calculation can be made on the fly when creating the graph.

Thanks

Comment: This most likely isn't going to work the way you want it to as your range will probably evaluate to a single number.  Check this out: [How to Divide a Range by a Range](http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-Divide-Range-by-Range-in-Excel-212993755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Named Range to accomplish this.  Create a Named Range that has the calculation you want to chart (e.g. named range value=Sheet1!$B$7:$W$7/Sheet1!$B$8:$W$8).  Then, add this Named Range as a data series to your chart and it will automatically calc your series for you-without the need of a "cheater row".